# I failed to send request to sandbox url with proxy in gitlab run, but the same could succeed at local run

Tags: typescript, proxy, gitlab, postman-testcase, docker-run

my request code is mocha framework, in local run using vs code, just npm run test by manually setting the proxy (export http_proxy=**), it could succeed to get 200 status code,, but the same failed at gitlab runner please advice me on this. your answer will be appriciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For hitting the api request in postman with required proxy,  it could succeed in local run, but it failed in gitlab CI running(docker running). please raise to me if additional info is required.